# Como reajustar texto que se encontra dentro de um TextFlow?

Tags: java, javafx

Estou com um problema, onde, ao tentar reajusta a tela, o texto que se encontra dentro de um `TextFlow`, vai pra fora da tela, e não é ajustado para baixo.

```
public SwingFXPanel(ServicosJson json) {
    this.json = json;
    this.cliente = cliente;        
    this.msgs = new ArrayList<>();               
    this.chatBox = new VBox();                            
    this.scroll = new ScrollPane();                
    this.lista = new ArrayList<>();
    this.scroll.setAccessibleRole(javafx.scene.AccessibleRole.PARENT);
    this.scroll.setHbarPolicy(javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    this.scroll.setLayoutX(0);
    this.scroll.setLayoutY(0);
    this.scroll.setPrefHeight(735);
    this.scroll.setPrefWidth(519);        
    this.scroll.setVvalue(1.0);        
    this.scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
    this.scroll.setFitToWidth(true);         
    this.scene = new Scene(this.scroll);
    this.scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/br/com/teste/commerce/chat/css/style.css").toString());    
    this.chatBox.heightProperty().addListener(observable -> scroll.setVvalue(1D));
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //
        }            
    });        
}

public void addMessage(String mensagem, String origem, boolean mostrandoAtalhos) {
        mensagem = mensagem.replace("u000A", "\n");
        Text text=new Text(mensagem);
        text.setFill(Color.BLACK);        
        text.getStyleClass().add("message");
        TextFlow tempFlow=new TextFlow();                     

        if(origem.equals("0")){            
            Text txtName=new Text();
            txtName.getStyleClass().add("txtName");
            tempFlow.getChildren().add(txtName);
        }
        if (mostrandoAtalhos) {
            text.setWrappingWidth(20);
            tempFlow.setMaxWidth(300);        
        } else {
            text.setWrappingWidth(80);
            tempFlow.setMaxWidth(650);        
        }
        tempFlow.getChildren().add(text);                
        TextFlow flow=new TextFlow(tempFlow);
        HBox hbox=new HBox(20);               
        Circle img =new Circle(32,32,16);

        img.getStyleClass().add("imageView");
        if (origem.equals("0")) {
            tempFlow.getStyleClass().add("tempFlowFlipped");
            flow.getStyleClass().add("textFlowFlipped");
            chatBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            hbox.getChildren().add(img);
            hbox.getChildren().add(flow);
        }else{
            text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            tempFlow.getStyleClass().add("tempFlow");
            flow.getStyleClass().add("textFlow");
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            hbox.getChildren().add(flow);
            hbox.getChildren().add(img);
        //}       
        }  
        hbox.getStyleClass().add("hbox");
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            chatBox.getChildren().addAll(hbox);                                    
        });      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o problema estava em que havia dois `TextFlow` dentro do outro, o primeiro continha um `maxWidth` e o outro não. Removi o segundo `TextFlow` e funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Esse bug aconteceu por conta dos múltiplos nós internos que você tem. Embora eu não saiba que tipo de painel você está usando para o chatBox eu fiz uns testes usando ele como HBox e consegui reproduzir o problema. Não ficou claro pra mim o tipo de tela que você deseja construir, mas o resize funcionará se for assim:

```
StringBuilder textoLongo = new StringBuilder();
textoLongo.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et ligula et dui efficitur gravida.");
textoLongo.append("Etiam pretium condimentum quam sit amet faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec nulla urna, pulvinar id ligula consectetur,");
textoLongo.append("pulvinar congue turpis. Donec convallis ultricies erat, ac bibendum augue tincidunt ut.");
textoLongo.append("Integer laoreet ipsum sed scelerisque aliquam. Nunc pulvinar urna nec tristique pulvinar.");
textoLongo.append("Praesent pretium tortor viverra tortor condimentum venenatis. Fusce a ipsum sem. Mauris malesuada venenatis ex,");
textoLongo.append("eu vestibulum est iaculis nec. Morbi finibus ligula vel commodo finibus. Ut gravida turpis id nisi sodales viverra.");
textoLongo.append("Donec lobortis ligula eu metus finibus congue. Morbi hendrerit, tellus non vestibulum ullamcorper,");
textoLongo.append("felis tortor facilisis orci, quis tempor justo nisl vitae magna");

Text text = new Text(textoLongo.toString());
TextFlow tf = new TextFlow(text);
tf.setPadding(new Insets(20.0,40.0,20.0,40.0));
chatBox = new HBox(tf);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O JavaFX ainda deixa um pouco a desejar em cenas muito complexas então você deve tentar construir seu layout o mais enxuto possível (É até melhor para performance)

Posso sugerir que use um BorderPane como principal (se você der mais detalhes do problema eu altero com outras sugestões). Outra coisa interessante no seu código são essas classes css:

```
img.getStyleClass().add("imageView"); // Já existe .image-view
hbox.getStyleClass().add("hbox"); // Já existe
```

**Edit:**

Abaixo uma implementação de uma janela de chat simples:

```
// Chat
text = new Text("Bem vindo ao chat");
TextFlow tf = new TextFlow(text);
tf.setPadding(new Insets(20.0,40.0,20.0,40.0));

// Scroll pane apenas vertical
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(tf); 
scroll.setFitToWidth(true);

// Opções do chat e botão de envio
TextField chat = new TextField();
Button enviar = new Button("Enviar");
HBox opcoes = new HBox(5);
chat.setPrefWidth(250.0);
opcoes.getChildren().setAll(chat, enviar);
opcoes.setPadding(new Insets(20.0,40.0,20.0,40.0));

// Painel principal
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setCenter(scroll);
root.setBottom(opcoes);

enviar.setOnAction((ActionEvent) -> {
    String textoAtual = text.getText();
    String novoTexto = chat.getText();
    text.setText(textoAtual + "\n\n" + novoTexto);
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou fazendo um chat simples. Essa parte é justamente onde ele adiciona as mensagens no painel. Eu atualizei o código para você ver melhor também

Comment: Outra observação é que essa tela é uma implementação de uma tela do JavaFX dentro de uma aplicação Swing

Comment: A compatibilidade entre os dois não é boa ... talvez por ser uma tela simples seja mais pertinente fazer em Swing mesmo.

Comment: O problema é que muitas coisas que eu preciso fazer não fica muito legal no Swing. Como essa parte visual do chat. Não é apenas um chat simples. Estou usando como base este código: https://github.com/Oshan96/ChatRoomFX